# Total Queue Percentage with Jquery Uploadify

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I am trying to calculate the total percentage of the queue in uploadify,

The onProgress built-in function returns the following:

**onProgress**

```
percentage 
bytesLoaded 
allBytesLoaded 
speed
```

At first I thought the 'percentage' would return the total percentage of the queue. However I later found out that it only returns the percentage of the item of which is being uploaded.

So my question is, can I calculate the total percent of all files and get the total of which has been uploaded?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

I guess by using the `onSelect` and/or `onSelectOnce` you could calculate the total percentage as these two callbacks

```
onSelect: fileObj
    size – The size in bytes of the file

onSelectOnce: data
    fileCount – The total number of files in the queue 
    allBytesTotal – The total number of bytes for all files in the queue
```

Extracted from [Uploadify Documentation](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/)